# What problems can I reduce Job Shop Scheduling to them

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, scheduling

I want to know which problems are harder than `Job Shop Scheduling` so I can reduce `JSP` to them.

Sorry I am new to these problems and looking for a source to know what are problems, what are their hardness variations and more ...

Comment: There are infinitely many problems that are harder than any given problem, so I don't think your question is really answerable.

Comment: Plus, different variants of Job Shop Scheduling have different complexities.

Comment: I saw an article (published in the 1960s) that proposed a 01 Integer Programming formulation for machine scheduling problems. I forgot the title of the article and the name of the author. You might want to look at "Machine Scheduling Problems: Classification, Complexity and Computations" by A.H.G. Rinooy Kan.